# What is the structure of $S$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, equivalence-relations

> Suppose we define an equivalence relation on $\mathbb R$ by $aRb$ iff $\{a\}=\{b\}$ for $a,b\in\mathbb R$. Here $\{.\}$ defines the fractional part. In other words, $aRb$ iff $a-b\in\mathbb Z$. Suppose $S$ is the collection of all equivalence classes defined by this equivalence relation. What is the structure of $S$?

So the way I proceeded is:

> Suppose $\bar{a}$ is the equivalence class for $a\in\mathbb R$. Then, $\bar{a}$ is the set of all real numbers located at integer distances from $a$. So $\bar{a}$ is a set of equidistant points (if we try to represent $\bar{a}$ graphically).
>
> The same is true for $\bar{b}$ for any other $b\in \mathbb R$. Every such equivalence class consists of a sequence of equidistant points.
>
> So the collection $S$ of these equivalence classes will be the entire real line!

But our professor drew $S$ as a circle containing all elements from $0$ to $1$ on the circumference, with $0$ and $1$ being the identical point on the circumference. He further hinted that we need to consider the function $z\mapsto e^{2\pi zi}$ for $z\in\mathbb R$. I don't understand this.

Comment: It would be a grave injustice to both @user2520938 and mathcounterexamples.net if I select any one best answer because they both have been prompt and have taken the pains to answer my doubts. They have really, really helped me in clearing my doubts. My sincere gratitude to them. Hence, I have upvoted their answers and I leave it to the community to decide which answer they deem is the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.**

Name $T$ the equivalence relation. And define $$
\begin{array}{l|rcl}
\varphi : & \mathbb R & \longrightarrow & \mathbb U\\
    & t & \longmapsto & e^{2i\pi t} \end{array}$$

You know that $\varphi$ is surjective. Now you will be able to prove that the inverse image of $z \in \mathbb U$ by $\varphi$ is an equivalence class of the equivalence relation $T$.

This proves that $\varphi$ induces a bijection $\overline{\varphi}$ between $S$ and $\mathbb U$. Which is exactly what your professor mentionned.

Comment: I want to clarify one thing: when I am drawing $S$, what should I plot? The elements of the equivalence classes themselves or their representatives in  each equivalence class?

Comment: Actually, he also mentioned an example: Define $aRb$ iff $|a|=|b|$ where $a,b\in\mathbb C$. Then he took $S$ as the collection of equivalence classes and drew $S$ as a collection of concentric circles. I understand why he did this because each equivalence class contains points of equal modulus, hence located on the same circle. But in this case, aren't we actually plotting the points $a,b$ on the same circle if they are in the same equivalence class?

Comment: Formally, an equivalence class of $T$ is a subset of $\mathbb R$ having one point in $[0,1)$ and the other ones are all the translated by translations of "integer values". By my map $\varphi$, this subset of the reals is mapped to one point of the unit circle.

Comment: You got it perfectly right. For your second equivalence relation, a circle is an equivalence class. Don't forget the origin, which is also an equivalence class having consisting only of a single point (youhave only one point $z \in \mathbb C$ with $\vert z \vert =0$.

Comment: Okay, so what I get is: drawing a structure for $S$ means we have to plot the representatives of the equivalence classes (which may be points, st. lines, circles, etc.). A bijective function if exists comes handy because then we just have to plot the image of the function. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 2):

This equivalence relation makes $0.1\equiv1.1\equiv2.1\equiv3.1$ as you have stated.  So each equivalence class has a representative on the unit interval $[0,1)$.  Since $1\equiv0$ it makes sense to tie the two ends of this interval together, making a circle.

Comment: But $S$ is the collection of equivalence classes, so each equivalence class contains NOT the "representative" but the elements themselves, in this case $\{...,0.1,1.1,2.1,...\}$ form an equivalence class. How can I just take their representative on the unit circle?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Show that $\psi : (\mathbb R, +) \to (S^1, \cdot)$ defined by $\psi (x) = e^{2\pi i x}$ is a homomorphism. Notice that $\ker \psi = \mathbb Z$. Then show that is isomorphic to $S^1$, by using the Isomorphism Theorem.

Where $S^1$ is the unitary circle and $S = \frac{\mathbb R}{\mathbb Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

Your reasoning shows that every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ is contained in some equivalence class, which is what you'd expect from an equivalence relation (an equivalence relation always partitions a set in disjoint equivalence classes). However, the elements of the collection of equivalence classes are (of course), equivalence classes, not individual element of $\mathbb{R}$.

So indeed $\bigcup_{\bar{a}\in S}\bar{a}=\mathbb{R}$, but this doesn't say anything about the structure of $S$. The equivalence class $\bar{a}$ can be identified with some element of $[0,1)$ (namely the element {a}). And since $\bar{0}=\bar{1}$ we can also identify the end point of this interval to form something looking a lot like a circle. Now it's up to you to maybe make this more concrete by using the hint.

---

Edit:
If you are asked to 'draw' $S$ without any other hints or notes, then that question is just very vague. You are right to be slightly confused then. This is the same as asking one to 'draw' $S=\{\{1\},\{2,3\},\emptyset\}$; There is no clear 'best'/'standard'/'obvious' way to draw this:

1. are we supposed to draw for each element in the untion of $S$ a single point on the real line?
2. Are we supposed to draw $1$ point for each subset of $S$ at the value of the average of that subset?
3. ... etc

So the answer is: if you are asked to make a drawing that 'shows' the structure of $S$, it is up to you to decide how to make this structure most clear using a drawing. In your original example the mapping to the unit circle seems like one of the best choices but, again, there is no $1$ unique right/best answer here.

Comment: I understand why $0$ and $1$ are joined. But let me get something straight: when I am drawing $S$ what should I plot? The points in the equivalence classes or the representatives of the equivalence classes(in which case $[0,1)$)?

Comment: When drawing $S$ you should (if you are looking to somehow show the structure of $S$ through this drawing) draw $1$ point for every element of $S$; so $1$ point for every equivalence class. Note however that the equivalence classes are sets of points of $\mathbb{R}$, so there is no fixed way of drawing those elements. Thats why you can use the suggested function, and 'associate' to each equivalence class $\bar{a}$ the point in $\mathbb{C}$: $e^{2\pi i \{a\}}$. There might be other ways mapping the points of $S$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$, but this is one of more 'natural' mappings given the deff of $S$

Comment: @LandonCarter Note the importance of the fact that the elements of $S$ are subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and so it's an essential part of the question to find a ways of associating to each such subset a unique point for example $\mathbb{R}^2$, preferably in way that somehow 'exposes' in a natural way the structure of $S$. And that there are multiple ways to make this mapping, some more natural than others.

Comment: @LandonCarter Note also, that it is not true that the elements of $[0,1)$ are 'THE' representatives for the equivalence classes. The element $5453.1$ in $\overline{0.1}$ is as valid a representative as the element $0.1$ or $1.1$ etc.

Comment: So suppose I want to say $a,b\in\mathbb C$ are related iff $|a|=|b|$. Then, it turns out that my equivalence class is a set of points with equal modulus, hence on the same circle centered at the origin. Now, my $S$ is the collection of all these concentric circles. However, in this case, are we not just plotting the points $a,b$, etc. or are we plotting the equivalence classes, i.e. the circles? I guess we are plotting the circles, isn't it? Otherwise we would have got the entire complex plane!!

Comment: Would you mind explaining the role of the function more precisely? Is it ought to be a bijection whose image is basically what we should plot when asked to draw he structure of $S$?

Comment: @LandonCarter See my edit.